# Use Let variable declaration with With Statement

Tags: javascript

I read about with statement from Ecma Specification and in there with statement evaluation like this.

1. Let val be the result of evaluating Expression.
2. Let obj be ? ToObject(? GetValue(val)).
3. Let oldEnv be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
4. Let newEnv be NewObjectEnvironment(obj, oldEnv).
5. Set the withEnvironment flag of newEnv's EnvironmentRecord to true.
6. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to newEnv.
7. Let C be the result of evaluating Statement.
8. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
9. Return Completion(UpdateEmpty(C, undefined)).

If with statement use Lexical Environment for evaluation why my sample code not work?

```
const user = {
   fullName: "Murad Sofiyev"
};
with(user) {
    let firstName = "Tofiq";
    fullName = "Tofiq Sofiyev";
}

console.log(user.firstName); // Undefined
console.log(user.fullName); // Tofiq Sofiyev
```

PS: I know with statement is deprecetaed but this is help me to understand Lexical Environment and Variable Environment :)

Answer (score 2):

The `{` following the `with(user)` creates an *entirely new* LexicalEnvironment. There are actually *two* environments created there: the environment for the `with`'d object, and the environment for the new `{` block. When you use `let firstName = "Tofiq";`, you're creating a new variable name inside the *inner* (block-scoped) environment.

This might be a bit more obvious if you can see that you can use `with` *without* a paired `{`:

```js
const user = {
   firstName: 'foo',
};
with(user);
console.log('Not a syntax error');
```

Here, the environment created by the `with`'d value is created, and goes completely unused. (and there's no inner environment).

Another issue is that `firstName` doesn't exist on the object. If the object had the `firstName` property *and* you used `var` instead of `let`, the new `Tofiq` would be assigned to the object.

```js
const user = {
   firstName: 'foo',
};
with(user) {
    var firstName = "Tofiq";
}

console.log(user.firstName); // Tofiq
// because var is not block-scoped
// so `var firstName` finds an outer Lexical Environment with that same variable name
```

Comment: You say we declared 2 ENV. But we can access object property from environment for the new { block. How it can be possible if there are have 2 ENV?

Comment: Because environments inherit from each other (this is exactly the same mechanism by which scopes inherit from each other); in normal code, `const a = 'a'; if (true) { console.log(a); }` works because the environment inside the `if` block can see outside to the `a` declared in the outer environment.

Comment: Sound interesting. This is mean there are create 2 nested environment :/

Comment: I was think before this is about Object Env Record and Declarative Env Record but you give me other point. But I don't know which is true )))

Answer (score 1):

Using `let` always creates a variable in block scope. So even though you use it inside the `with` block, it is creating a new variable scope to the `with`. You might want that behaviour if you needed to do some calculations inside the block.